# Was St Joseph alive during the initial stages of Jesus' public life?

Tags: matthew, jesus, joseph

Traditions have it that St.Joseph was no more when Jesus started his public life at the age of thirty. But then, we see the people of Jesus' hometown commenting , in Mtt 13: 54- 55 (KJV)

> And when he was come into his own country, he taught them in their synagogue, insomuch that they were astonished, and said, Whence hath this man this wisdom, and these mighty works? Is not this the carpenter's son?

<  The Jews are not referring to St Joseph as a deceased person, but as a living one who is  known by his profession. On the other hand, the Gospels do not mention the death of St Joseph. That he was no more at the time of Jesus' crucifixion is attested by the fact that the Blessed Mother's care is entrusted to Apostle John.  A doubt still remains as to why the Jews referred to ' the carpenter ' as though St Joseph was alive at the time. How  do Bible  scholars explain the reference ?

Comment: "*The Jews are not referring to St Joseph as a deceased person, but as a living one*" is an untrue assertion.  All it says is that Joseph is either known or had been well-know.  It says nothing about whether he was living or dead.

Comment: All that we know is that Joseph was alive when Jesus was 12 years old at the temple after which he is never mentioned again.

Comment: I tend to speculate, but this time I will say - quoting @Dottard himself - "we are not told, so we don't know."

Comment: Thanks, Dottard. Let us presume that Joseph was the only carpenter available at Nazareth. On his death, the mantle would fall on someone else preferably his son. Note that Jesus himself is called ' the carpenter ' in Mk 6:3.  Of course persons who are one of its kind in various fields like art are known by their profession long after death, say Michaelangelo, the Sculptor. But carpentry is not a profession that sticks to one's name even after one's death . Is it ?

Comment: The Definite Article ' the' is peculiar to English. Many languages use the demonstrative adjectives ' this'  ' that'  etc while referring to persons and objects. It is possible that the Jews referred to St Joseph as  ' that carpenter ' .

Answer (score 2):

The New Testament does not answer this question. The most detailed ancient source (I am aware of) that treats this subject is [The History of Joseph the Carpenter](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0805.htm); which indicates that Joseph died when Jesus was approximately 19 years old.

However, note that the authorship and provenance of *The History of Joseph the Carpenter* are unknown, it does not cite sources, and it appears to have been written ~5 centuries after the fact. It also commits some fairly obvious errors of known history.

From the New Testament itself:

- Joseph is alive when Jesus is twelve (see Luke 2:41-43)
- I agree with the OP's conclusion that Joseph is not alive at the time of the crucifixion, or it would not have been necessary to entrust Mary to John's care (John 19:26-27)
- I don't see that Matt 13:54-55 is an indication that Joseph is still living -- he's simply referred to as someone who was known in the community. At a stretch, I'd draw the inference that Joseph is *not* living when Jesus ministers in Nazareth, as he is conspicuously absent from the "mother & brethren" who are there, and the angry crowd in Nazareth is asking "isn't this Joseph's son" as opposed to bringing in Joseph himself and asking "isn't this *your* son?" However, this conclusion is somewhat speculative.

We do not know when Joseph died, but it appears likely that he passed sometime between when Jesus was 12 and when Jesus died.